# ion-textarea push the ion-header all the way to the top and hide it

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-view

I am currently working with the latest version of ionic, I am using a textarea in data entry page. after the user clicks on the textarea the keyboard shows up and whole page goes up. The issue is it also push the header and makes it hidden. 
I the Back button and the Save button are both on the navbar. And then the user get confused where the save button is.

Is there any workaround this issue.?
Thanks

Comment: make sure that you put `Save` and `Back ` buttons outside `ion-content`

Comment: or provide html of the entry page

Answer (score 0):

does your entry page look like below?

```
<ion-header no-shadow no-border>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title text-uppercase>XXXXXXX</ion-title>    
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
...
</ion-content>
```

Comment: <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar no-border-bottom color="ios-blue">
    <ion-title>
      {{model?.UniqueKey}}
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button type="button" (click)="onSave()"> Save </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

Comment: Almost the same

Comment: then without providing code, no one can tell. Sorry